# Unable to fetch user Facebook email upon login to iOS app

Tags: swift

I am trying to fetch Facebook info on my users for an iOS app. I am able to fetch everything on their public_profile, but, when i try to fetch the user_email, the app crashes because it is trying to unwrap a nil optional. I should be able to fetch user_email without a problem, as Facebook does not require specific authorization. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your current code, please!

Comment: Are you using Facebook SDK v4.4? There were some adjustments made regarding getting the email upon login. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314124/get-email-and-name-facebook-sdk-v4-4-0-swift

Comment: if let user_email = data["user_email"] as? String {}

Comment: You have to request for the email. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312744/not-getting-email-and-public-profile-using-facebook-4-4-0-sdk/31331502#31331502