# Fb login email field not getting in API V. 2.4

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

My code is not working only getting id and name.

Previously apps my same code works fine.

But in this I am not getting mail ID.

Any solution to get email field ?

Here is my code.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {

        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error)
        {

             if (!error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"%@",user);

                 [self onSuccessDoUserRegistration:user];
             }
         }];
    }
```

Result Debug Code po user

```
{
    id = 971082636277480;
    name = "Apps Dev";
}
```

Comment: You have to ask for the email field with the parameters. Without that Facebook will only provide id and name. Please check the change-log at Facebook. hope you will find the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312744/not-getting-email-and-public-profile-using-facebook-4-4-0-sdk/

Comment: NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"email", nil];
    
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
    {
        [[Loader sharedInstance] stop];
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    }];

Comment: Above is my read permission code . Can i change this ?

Comment: I think you need to update your SDK and code also

Comment: @iApps no read permission is ok. Just to add parameters when you want to get the data from graph request

Comment: @ashish pls tell me where can i add parameters ?

Comment: @iApps you are using swift or objective-c?

Comment: Can i update in above session state Change method ?

Comment: @ashish objective C can you give me update code ?

Comment: @iApps added an answer . hope it helps you.

Comment: I know my problem in         [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, this code