# iOS - Facebook SDK v.4.5.1 - fetch user name and email

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I am integrating the Facebook login into my app. The SDK is perfectly installed - I have tested everything. I am also able to log in and log out perfectly.
But now the most important part: I don't know how to fetch the data I need (user name, email address, etc.).

I currently declare the LoginButton in my header file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton;
```

Then I have this in my main file:

```
    loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
loginButton.delegate = self;
loginButton.readPermissions =
@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];
```

I have also implemented the two methods I need -- and they are correctly called.

```
    - (void)  loginButton:  (FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:  (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:  (NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"facebook login button test");



}
- (void) loginButtonDidLogOut:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton{
    NSLog(@"facebook logout button test");
}
```

What is the next step? All the tutorials online are outdated or in Swift. I mainly need to know the user's name, email and if he is logged in or not (for later on).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can check this answer : [Not getting Email and public profile using facebook 4.4.0 SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31331502/3202193)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it from following method.

```
- (void)getFacebookData{
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, name, id, gender"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
             }
         }];
    }
}
```

Then call this method as follow.

```
- (void)  loginButton:  (FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton
didCompleteWithResult:  (FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result
                error:  (NSError *)error{

    NSLog(@"facebook login button test");

   [self getFacebookData];

}
```

By this way you can get all information about user.

Comment: Thanks a lot Piyush, it works very well. In getFacebookData, how can I get the first_name for example from the "result"?

Comment: can u tell me what's log of NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);  ?

Comment: It's OK I found the solution, I just had to recreate the dictionary: NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;