# not Getting user's email Personal info from Facebook in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

In my app i have to implement facebook login .based on the facebook documentation i am doing integration but when i am fetching users info email section is coming null for me .
can some one tell me where is the issue .
this code i am using

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    //login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorBrowser;
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             // Process error
         }
         else if (result.isCancelled)
         {
             // Handle cancellations
         }
         else
         {
             if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
             {
                 NSLog(@"result is:%@",result);

                 [login logOut]; // Only If you don't want to save the session for current app
             }
         }
     }];
    if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
    {
        NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);



        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

             if (!error) {



                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@  and Email : %@", result,result[@"email"]);
             }
         }];
    }

}
```

getting out put this

```
fetched user:{
    id = 970029739773026393591;
    name = "jace";
}  and Email : (null)
FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass paramenter `email` to fetch user_email through Facebook:

```
///Add This line
NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                     [parameters setValue:@"id,name,email" forKey:@"fields"];

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters] <--------- This line

startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error)
                          {

                          }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Facebook` has upgraded the permissions, so follow like this

change this line

```
 [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
```

into

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location , friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
```

additional [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312744/not-getting-email-and-public-profile-using-facebook-4-4-0-sdk)

Comment: @PRK -- tanx a lot bro

Answer (score 1):

you have to get user email like this

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_friends",@"user_birthday"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 // Process error
                 NSLog(@"error is :%@",error);
             }
             else if (result.isCancelled)
             {
                 // Handle cancellations
                 NSLog(@"error is :%@",error);
             }
             else
             {
                 if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
                 {
                     NSLog(@"Login successfull");
                     [self fetchUserInfo];
                 }
             }
         }];
    }

    -(void)fetchUserInfo
    {
        if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
        {
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id,name,link,first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error)
                 {
                  NSLog(@"result : %@",result);
                 }
             }];

        }
    }
```