# re request Facebook permissions with Facebook sdk 3.x in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I am using facebook sdk 3.14 and requesting user for`public profile, email, user_photos permissions`. I am using **email** for login purpose. If user denies email during login , there is no way to ask it back. But i have seen apps like **Airbnb** and **Zomato** returning user back to permissions page unless all the reuired permissions are given by the user.

Is there a way in which i can re-request the user for permissions that were not granted during the login process.

I am using the below code for requesting the permissions

```
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends",@"user_photos"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         // Retrieve the app delegate


         if(error.code ==2 && [errorReason isEqualToString:@"com.facebook.sdk:UserLoginCancelled"]){
             [facebookWebobj performSelector:@selector(hideAnimatedLoader) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
         }
         else
         {
         // get email id and login the user
         }

     }];
```

Comment: Use latest Facebook SDK 4.x (4.6)

Comment: @iAshish i would have to change a lot of code to use 4.x which is not feasible at the moment. Is there a work around in 3.x?

Comment: You have to do that. Facebook giving less support to old SDK's.

Comment: It's easy. Check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312744/not-getting-email-and-public-profile-using-facebook-4-4-0-sdk/31331502#31331502